# When I am sending get method request in jmeter its giving me an error java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index

Tags: jmeter

When I am sending `GET` method request in jmeter its giving me an error

Response:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 63: http://52.30.181.28:9000/PlatformServices/api/v2.0/kartCharges/{"pincode":560001,"gatewayPaymentMode":"NA","kartInfo":[{"sellerId":"S10014","qty":30,"unitPrice":1999,"sku":"SKU0100"}]}
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:939)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:286)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Request:

```
GET http://52.30.181.28:9000/PlatformServices/api/v2.0/kartCharges/{"pincode":560001,"gatewayPaymentMode":"NA","kartInfo":[{"sellerId":"S10014","qty":30,"unitPrice":1999,"sku":"SKU0100"}]}
```

[no cookies]

Answer (score 2):

Your request body is in json format.

So in HTTP Header Manager add content-type as application/json.

Then put  below part in url:
 http://52.30.181.28:9000/PlatformServices/api/v2.0/kartCharges/

And put rest in body part.
    ={"pincode":560001,"gatewayPaymentMode":"NA","kartInfo":[{"sellerId":"S10014","qty":30,"unitPrice":1999,"sku":"SKU0100"}]}